# Connect three tables with a single SQL-Query

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have this three tables:

```
table1: id, title, content
connection: id_t1, id_t2
table2: id, title, content
```

In my case I just select a **single** row of table1. For this result there are **many** rows in table2. The connection of both tables can be found in the table 'connection'

How do I have to create the query to get this result?

```
table1-title
table2-content1
table2-content2
table2-content3
table1-content
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I believe you want to use GROUP BY with the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) function
The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT table1.title, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.content) as table2.group_content, table1.content
FROM table1
JOIN connection on table1.id = id_t1
JOIN table2 on connection.id_t2 = table2.id
GROUP BY table2.content
```

This would give you one row for each table1.id, with multiple table2.content rows concatenated into one column (called table2.group_content in this example).

Answer (score 0):

```
select title from table1 where title_id = 1
UNION
select t2.content 
from table2 t2, table1 t1, connection c  
where t1.title_id = 1
    and t1.title_id = c.id_t1
    and c.id_t2 = t2.title_id
UNION
select content from table1 where title_id = 1
```

Comment: 1. This should use `UNION ALL` to get the order right, 2. Using `INNER JOIN` would be better, 3. Please add some explanation to your code